# Ring of Integers of Number Field

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field (therefore a finite algebraic extension $K/ \mathbb{Q}$). Since this extension is separable the primitive element theorem says $K= \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. Denote by $A$ its ring of integers.

Remark: $A:= \{a \in K \vert   \exists f \in \mathbb{Z}[X]: f(a)=0 \}$

Denote by $N:K \to \mathbb{Q}$ the [norm map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_norm).

My question is how to deduce that is for $a \in A$ if we have $N(a)= \pm 1$ then $a \in A^*$ (=invertible elements in $A$)

My attempts: I know that $N$ is a multiplicative map and $A$ a local ring.

I suppose that assuming that $a= pq$ with $p \text{ or} q \in A \backslash A^*$ lead to a contradiction. But why?

Comment: $\frac{3}{5}+\frac{4}{5}i$

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention that we futhermore assume $a \in A$!

Comment: Your definition of $A$ is incomplete. You need $f$ to be **monic**; otherwise, you are claiming that $A=K$.

Comment: Otherwise $|N(a)| = \# A/(a)$ so $|N(a)|= 1$ implies $(a)=(1)$ (pick a group isomorphism $\phi : A \to \Bbb{Z}^n$, $\phi(ax)= M \phi(x)$ for some $M \in M_n(\Bbb{Z})$ then $\# A/(a) = \# \Bbb{Z}/M\Bbb{Z} = |\det(M)|$ and $N(a)=\det(M)$ by definition)

Answer (score 1):

Let $L$ be the Galois closure of $K$, and let $B$ be the ring of integers of $L$. Note that $A\subseteq B$. To avoid confusion, let $N_K$ be the norm map of $K$.

If $N_K(a)=\pm 1$, then the product of all Galois conjugates of $a$ (possibly raised to some power, if $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ is properly contained in $K$), is $1$ or $-1$; all of these conjugates lie in $B$, and so $a$ is a unit in $B$: for if the conjugates of $a$ are $a,\sigma_2(a),\ldots,\sigma_m(a)$, then $a^{-1}=\pm\sigma_2(a)\cdots\sigma_m(a)$ (or, if $\mathbb{Q}(a)\subsetneq K$, something of the form $\pm a^{r-1}(\sigma_2(a)\cdots\sigma_m(a))^r$ for some $r$).

But that means that $a^{-1}\in B$. Thus, $a^{-1}$ is an algebraic integer; since $a\in K$, $a^{-1}\in K$ and is an algebraic integer, it follows that in fact $a^{-1}\in A$; that is, $a$ is a unit in $A$.